# Why do old versions exist?

Tags: 7

In [Issues for Drupal core](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal), different versions of Drupal were mentioned. If Drupal 8 is obviously better than Drupal 7 and prior versions, why do the issues for Drupal 7 exist?

Comment: Because Drupal 7 has LTS until Drupal 9, not to mention many sites still using it. Just because a new version is out doesn't mean the previous one should be nuked from existence.

Comment: If you're new to Drupal and are going to building a complex site, D7 is still arguably better. It will likely be supported in terms of security for like 5 more years. In a few years, the contrib modules will have caught up to D7 and migrations will be easier.

Comment: That's kind of subjective and really really depends on a project by project basis. Plenty of complex sites have been built in D8.

Comment: @NiallMurphy That's definitely a per project/per person (or organisation) opinion. All the complex sites I've built in Drupal 8 have been far easier to develop, easier for the client to administer, and generally more satisfying to work with than any of the D7 sites I built in 5+ years of doing so. It's true that some contrib modules haven't been ported yet, but Drupal 8 makes it infinitely easier to develop any missing functionality yourself. I would say site-builders might prefer D7, developers will vastly prefer D8, so it depends who you are

Comment: @Clive I understand that. My comment was specifically about being new to Drupal (which suggests not working in a company. no one working as a web dev would ask the OP's question.), and building complex sites.. D7 is arguably better if the site has certain requirements that someone doesn't have the ability to add themselves in D8. eg. Editable fields. There are still lots of people who develop sites for themselves in D7 and benefit from years of contrib development there.

Comment: @Niall I was just pointing out the counter to your argument that d7 is better. I don’t agree that you can make a statement like that, it depends too much on the context of a project and which person or organisation/team is making the decision. My own opinion about D8 being a lot better was just there to demonstrate balance for the OP. Yes, D7 is arguably better, but it’s also arguably worse :)

Comment: Yeah, I've no doubt that you're right. I'm thinking from my own perspective as not even working in the web dev industry. I'd build any new sites in D8 now that I have the confidence in my coding to make up for any lost D7 benefits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the version 8 of drupal exists which is obviously better than drupal 7

Yep Drupal 8 is arguably better, but...so what? When a car manufacturer releases a new version of a model, does everyone throw out the old model immediately and just get a new one? Of course not; if they can, and wish, to upgrade to the latest version, they'll do so in their own time.

In the meantime it would be ridiculous for mechanics to stop fixing the older model, right?

Same story here.

Answer (score 2):

Because still a lot of sites using drupal 7 and drupal 8 still not perfect. For example drupal 7 has more supported modules than drupal 8. As I know there's still drupal 6 sites.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an attempt to give an answer to this part of your question:

> why do the issues for Drupal 7 exist?

Consider a distribution such as [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), which contains [this `.make` file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_kickstart/tree/drupal-org.make).

Line 17 of this `.make` file looks like so:

```
projects[features][patch][2479803] = "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ignore_hidden_modules-2479803-1.patch"
```

In other words, to install Commerce Kickstart, this is one of the patches that needs to be applied also. In this specific case the patch appears to be related to the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module, as detailed/explained in the issue titled [Ignore hidden modules when mapping components.](https://www.drupal.org/project/features/issues/2479803) ... a D7 issue, did you notice?!?! More specifically, [comment # 1 of that very issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/features/issues/2479803#comment-9874521) is where that patch (as referred to in the make file) was posted.

So with that, its because that D7 issue (still) exists, that it is (still) possible to install Commerce Kickstart. This is just 1 specific example, but there are zillions of patches that exist throughout drupal.org. And if you really think about it, consider the issue queue as some sort of online storage to not only attach such patches to, but also to get an idea (aka documentation) about what a specific patch is about.

But wait, there is even more: your question is only about D7, the beauty of all this is that it applies to any Drupal version, starting as of Drupal 4.x, and including 5.x and 6.x also. So to continue the "*car manufacturer* metaphor from a previous example: the issue queue is like the (very only!) warehouse to find the spare parts for the old models also ... including the instructions/documentation about them.

PS: the patch example I used here is about a contributed module. Though there are similar patches that are related to Drupal core. Such as what is described in the question about "[Patch a module loaded by a distribution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/69776/39516)".